# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Where exactly does the header go?

Tags: html, rest, access-control

I am trying to send a username and password to a rest service, but I keep getting this error. I read that I need a header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); to get past this, but I don't understand where it goes. Does it go in the client side application or the server side? And where exactly?

Comment: The server you're sending the username and password should reply to you with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header.

Answer (score 1):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is an HTTP *response* header.  It is sent from the server (your REST API in this case) in the response for the data requested.

Comment: ... And if you are in the position to set that header you should think twice if it is a good idea to set an asterisk or a specific host: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/